# Tabulator add a new row and edit content

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have following Tabulator setup:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#data-table", {
            layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table
            columns: [ //Define Table Columns
                { title: "Name", field: "name", editor:"input" },
                { title: "IP", field: "ip" },
            ],
            index:"name"
        });
```

Also, I register a function to insert a new row:

```
function insertRow(){
            table.addData([{
                name: "",
                ip: "",
            }], true).then(function(rows){
                if (rows.length == 0) return;
                rows[0].getCell("name").edit();
            })

        }
```

When I call the function `insertRow()`, it can insert a new row into the table but not open editing for the first cell.
However, following code works:

```
if (rows.length == 0) return;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    rows[0].getCell("name").edit();
                }, 100);
```

In the documentation http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/update,

> The addData method returns a promise, this can be used to run any
> other commands that have to be run after the data has been loaded into
> the table. By running them in the promise you ensure they are only run
> after the table has loaded the data.

So, it seem that we cannot call `rows[0].getCell("name").edit()` immediately inside the promise.
Is this correct?
Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only adding one row, use the `addRow` function instead of the `addData` function:

```js
table.addRow({name: "", ip: ""], true)
.then(function(row){
   rows.getCell("name").edit();
});
```